# Parallel list properties

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of control items, and another list of their attributes. Since these lists directly parallel each other, I iterate through the list of attributes to apply them to the controls:

The two lists in question are `List<TableCell> calTitleCol` and `List<DayOfWeek> dayList`.

```
            foreach (DayOfWeek day in dayList)
            {
                int index = dayList.IndexOf(day);
                string dayStr = day.ToString();
                dayStr = dayStr.Substring(0, 3);
                calTitleCol[index].Text == dayStr;


                if (day == DayOfWeek.Saturday || day == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    //more parameters here
                }
            }
```

I would have assumed that the line reading `calTitleCol[index].Text == dayStr;` was perfectly logical, however the error appearing at this line reads "Only assignment, call  can be used as a statement". Is this not assignment? Logically, shouldn't this action be perfectly legal?

Comment: what you are trying to do in `calTitleCol[index].Text == dayStr;`? even if it was legal this just gives you a useless boolean value.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that what you are trying to do is an assignment.

For that, you should change `calTitleCol[index].Text == dayStr;` to  `calTitleCol[index].Text = dayStr;`

The `==` operator is an equality operator.

The `=` is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DayOfWeek day in dayList)
            {
                int index = dayList.IndexOf(day);
                string dayStr = day.ToString();
                dayStr = dayStr.Substring(0, 3);
                calTitleCol[index].Text = dayStr;
-----------------------------------------^ // Why double equals?

                if (day == DayOfWeek.Saturday || day == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    //more parameters here
                }
            }
```

You are doing assignment . 
Double `==` means you are comparing the results. 
Single `=` Assignment.